# Сохранение checkbox состояния SharedPreferences

Tags: android

Я ставлю галочку только одному или двум checkboxам после перезагрузки галочки ставятся во всех checkboxах. Как решить подскажите?

```
public class TaskAdapt extends BaseAdapter  {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Task> taskses;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    String PACKAGE_NAME;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    boolean [] itemChecked;

    public TaskAdapt(Context context, ArrayList<Task> taskses) {
        this.context = context;
        this.taskses = taskses;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        itemChecked = new boolean[taskses.size()];
    }
    class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox check_task;
        TextView textView;
    }
    Task getTask(int i) {
        return ((Task) getItem(i));
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return taskses.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return taskses.get(i);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        View myView = view;
        if (myView == null) {
            myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_task, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.check_task = (CheckBox) myView.findViewById(R.id.task_check);
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.task_text);
            myView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) myView.getTag();
        }

        final Task t = getTask(i);
        viewHolder.textView.setText(String.valueOf(t.task_name));




        sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        for(int k = 0; k<taskses.size(); k++){

            viewHolder.check_task.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(PACKAGE_NAME , false));

        }

        viewHolder.check_task.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PACKAGE_NAME , Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                if (viewHolder.check_task.isChecked()) {
                    itemChecked[i] = true;
                    viewHolder.check_task.setChecked(true);
                    editor.putBoolean(PACKAGE_NAME, true);
                    Log.d("put true", "TRUE" + i);
                    editor.apply();

                } else {
                    itemChecked[i] = false;
                    viewHolder.check_task.setChecked(false);
                    editor.putBoolean(PACKAGE_NAME, false);
                    Log.d("put false", "FALSE" + i);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        });

        return myView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно сохранять не одно значение, а весь массив `itemChecked`. И, соответственно при запуске его восстанавливать и в адаптере брать значения для чекбоксов уже из массива.

Comment: Можете показать пример а то я начинающий смысл понял но реализовать не смог

Answer (score 1):

Привет. Просто сериализуй свой массив boolean[] в строку, эту строку сохраняй в SharedPreferences, и потом десериализуй обратно.

```
public void serialization() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String[] strs = new String[] {"test 1", "test 2", "test 3"};
    Log.d("serializing", Arrays.toString(strs));

    // serialize
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    new ObjectOutputStream(out).writeObject(strs);

    // your string
    String yourString = Hex.encodeHex(out.toByteArray());
    Log.d("serializing", yourString);

    // deserialize
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(Hex.decodeHex(String.valueOf(yourString.toCharArray())));
    Log.d("serializing", Arrays.toString((String[]) new ObjectInputStream(in).readObject()));
}
```

Только надо вот что учитывать. Лучше всего это делать один раз. 
потому что пока ты работаешь с адаптером, нет смысла вносить изменения в SP. Только лишний раз память дергаешь. Не продуктивно. Лучший вариант такой.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CheckboxAdapter adapter; // это твой адаптер
    SharedPreferences preferences; // это SP

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ...

        adapter.loadData(preferences.getSerializedArray()) // тут загружаешь свои данные из сериализованного массива 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        preferences.setSerializedArray(adapter.getBooleanArray());   
    }
}
```